# How to enable http requests on Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, networking, virtual-machine, firewall, telnet

I have an Ubuntu VM in Azure with inbound port rules configured as shown:[image]
As you can see, HTTP connections are allowed, however I am unable to telnet the public IP from my computer on port 80. I have also tried to check the HTTP connection from the Azure portal and it shows that connectivity is allowed.[image]
Is there anything else that I should do to be able to telnet to this VM?

Comment: Please verify you have some service listening on port 80.  Also ensure you don't have a firewall at the OS level blocking port 80.

Comment: Yes, it was the firewall at the OS level, thank you!